# How do I remove unknown, extra, data values from large file?

Tags: python, image, csv, tensorflow, image-classification

I am working on an Python, TensorFlow, image classification model, and in my training images, I have 12,611 images, but in my training labels, I have 12,613. (each image has a number as the title, and this number corresponds to the same number in a CSV file with the accompanying information for that image).

From here, what I need to do is simply remove those 2 extra data points for which I don't have pictures for. How can I write a code to help with this?

(If the code tells me which data points are the extras, I can manually remove them from the CSV file)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sounds uncannily similar to when folks get directory listings that include `.` and `..`

Answer (score 0):

Well its very straightforward, you can try something like this (As I dont kno exactly how and where you have saved your images, you might have to update the code to meet your use case) :

```py
dir_path = r'/path/to/folder/of/images'
csv_path = r'/path/to/csv/file'
images = []

# Get all images labels
for filename in os.listdir(dir_path):
    images.append(int(filename.split('.')[0]))

# Read CSV
df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)

# Print which labels are extra
for i in df['<COLUMN_NAME>'].tolist():
    if i not in images:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Hi, I have inputted my own info with my image path as '/Users/downloads/Boneage_competition/training_dataset/Resized/'
and my csv file as
'/Users/FOLDEER/downloads/train.csv'
 and my <column name> as "id"
but I am getting an error message as follows: 
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-5dc62b736fbf> in <module>
      5 # Get all images labels
      6 for filename in os.listdir(dir_path):
----> 7     images.append(int(filename))
      8 
      9 # Read CSV

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3975.png'

Comment: Hi, I have updated the answer check if it works now

Comment: Hi, I am getting the same error, but now it looks like this:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Comment: That would occur if there is a `.<EXTENSION>` file in your directory, make sure its all images in the form `<NUMBER>.<EXTENSION>`